# &reg becomes ® in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery code where I am trying to append to an existing div a label tag which contains a URL. Below is the code:

```
var strURL = 'http://financials.morningstar.com/ratios/r.htmlt=tup&region=usa&culture=en-US';
var str = '<li>';
str += '<label style="font-family:Arial;">' + strURL + '</label>';
str += '</li>';
$('#existingDiv').append(str);
```

When the page is actually displayed it shows the URL as:

> http://financials.morningstar.com/ratios/r.html?t=tup®ion=usa&culture=en-US

Comment: try [encodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) before appending

Comment: I can't duplicate the problem, can you make a jsfiddle that demonstrates it?

Comment: what browser?  AFAIK the `&reg` shouldn't get recognised as an HTML entity without a trailing semicolon

Comment: Happens on all major browsers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A ***quick fix*** would be to add the label as a *text* as a second step after appending the *html* to the `existingDiv` - see demo below:

```js
var strURL = 'http://financials.morningstar.com/ratios/r.htmlt=tup&region=usa&culture=en-US';
var str = '<li>';
str += '<label style="font-family:Arial;">' + '</label>';
str += '</li>';
$('#existingDiv').append(str);
$('#existingDiv label').text(strURL);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="existingDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. That did the trick.